# How to ingest an elastic search database definition file

Tags: elasticsearch

I got a file with some definitions for an elastic search database in the following format:

```
PUT /drafts
{
  "settings": {
        "max_result_window" : "100000"
        }
}

PUT /drafts/draft/_mapping
{
"draft":{
      "properties":{
         "id":{
            "type":"keyword"
         },
         "analysis_id":{
            "type":"keyword"
         }
      }
   }
}

PUT /variants
{
  "settings": {
          "analysis": {
          "normalizer": {
                "lowercase_normalizer": {
                "type": "custom",
                "char_filter": [],
            "filter": ["lowercase"]
                }
        }
        },
        "max_result_window" : "100000"
        }
}
```

How can I ingest that into my elastic search server in bulk?

I tried the _bulk api call but that does not seem to work

```
curl localhost:9200/_bulk -d @file
```

I have seen this format in the elastic search tutorials but it never states how to run those files...Is it even possible

Answer (score 0):

Bulk API is for indexing/ updating / deleting . Operations mentioned above are either altering mapping or adding settings to indexing. This is not possible with bulk API.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html